# Can I flash an English recovery image onto a Japanese Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I have a Japanese Surface Pro 3 that I would like to convert to a 100% English version of Windows.

I have followed other guides and have "converted" the existing Japanese Windows installation to be 99% English, but it is still slightly non-English in a few places:

- The blue Windows update screens during a reboot are still in Japanese
- I can type/read in English fine, but the fonts look slightly off i.e. a different font is used than I am used to

I can enter my serial number and download a recovery image from https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/surfacerecoveryimage . The URL suggests that it will be en-NZ, but will it actually be the standard English image or will it use my serial number and give me a JP image? If it does give me an en-NZ image, will it actually install OK?

Comment: Only the Single Language versions of Windows 10 have regional/language limits.  If you want an English installation, download the current Windows 10 ISO and use that instead.  Why are using en-nz instead of en-us if you want to guarantee the image downloaded will be English? The drivers for your Surface Pro can be downloaded separately

Comment: I don't want en-us because I don't live in the US and I want the quirks of NZ English and regional defaults. The download site doesn't actually give me any information about the download, I am just redirected to the en-nz site after logging in. The download failed after 8 hours, so I wasn't able to inspect the zip file. I assume that the recovery image will contain extra things that the standard iso wont e.g. surface recovery or firmware options.

Comment: The only difference is the drivers are included which can be downloaded and installed after Windows is installed.  I still suggest you try the current Windows 10 ISO with the language of your choice